# List("foo") foreach print other synonyms?

Tags: scala

I want to put the print behind
like

```
"foo" match {
    case str => println(str)
}
```

or

```
List("foo") foreach print
```

Are there other best one?

like in Haskell

```
 return "foo" >>= print
```

Comment: Define what you mean by "best".

Comment: Will `"foo".print()` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

so if you just want to have somewhat haskell like semantics you can try the [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) or the [scalaz](https://scalaz.github.io/7/) libraries. both have `IO` monads (cats in cats-effects) that would allow you to use the `print` in a principled manner as in your last example. If you don't care about the purity aspect you could also achieve this with the `Id` Monad which also both libraries offer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
case class Print(v: String) {
  def print = Predef.print(v)
}

object Print {
  implicit def stringToString(s: String) = new Print(s)
}

import Print._

object App extends App {

  "foo".print 
  "bar" print
}
```